# Getting this error while trying to decrypt in NodeJS. [Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data]

Tags: node.js, go, encryption, aes

Getting the above error while trying to decrypt image data in NodeJS. Below are the details.

- Algo - aes-256-gcm
- Encryption - Golang
- Decryption - Nodejs
- Data Encrypted - image

**Encryption Golang Code**

```
 func EncryptData(data []byte, passphrase string) ([]byte, error) {
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(createHash(passphrase)))
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ciphertext := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, data, nil)
}
```

**Decryption NodeJS Code**

```
 async function decrypt(data, enc_key) {

    if (!enc_key) {
        console.log("Encryption key is undefined")
        return
    }

    try {

        let decryptedEncKey = await encryptedKey(enc_key);
        console.log('The decrypted key inside decrypt function is: ', decryptedEncKey);

        const length = data.length;
        const iv = data.slice(0, IV_SIZE);
        const tag = data.slice(length - TAG_SIZE, length);
        let encryptedData = data.slice(IV_SIZE, length - TAG_SIZE);

        // AES 256 GCM Mode
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', decryptedEncKey, iv);
        decipher.update(encryptedData, 'null', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary'));
        return decipher.update(encryptedData, 'null', 'binary') + decipher.final('binary');
    
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log("Error in image decription");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The NodeJS code is missing the setting of the authentication tag with `decipher.setAuthTag(tag)`. The *double* `decipher.update(...) + decipher.final(...)` is also wrong, but probably that's just a typo since it wasn't there [at the start](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75590751/2).